# Is C# SortedList<TKey, TValue>.Keys.Contains method throwing a null exception a good thing?

Tags: c#, specifications, sortedlist

Consider this piece of code (also available [in Ideone](http://ideone.com/94phrr)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(HasItem(new List<string>(), null));
        try {
            Console.WriteLine(HasItem(new SortedList<string, int>().Keys, null));
        } catch (ArgumentNullException) {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException");
        }
    }

    public static bool HasItem(ICollection<string> collection, string item) {
        return collection.Contains(item);
    }
}
```

## Problem

The output is

> False
>
> ArgumentNullException

After digging through how does the [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx) works I found that this call is equivalent to invoking [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>.ContainsKey(TKey key)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.Generic.SortedList%602.ContainsKey);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method, which has an `ArgumentNullException` documented.

On the other hand, documentation for the [`ICollection<T>.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56(v=vs.110).aspx) method states:

> Returns: `true` if item is found in the `ICollection<T>`; otherwise, `false`.

Well, `null` isn't a part of the second collection in my example, so I expect `false` to be returned. An `ArgumentNullException` is a violation of the interface, and thus, a bug.

What is a workaround for that in production code? Type checking will be very ugly, given that the [`.Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132379(v=vs.110).aspx) property returns an instance of a private generic nested class, and I don't have any other ideas. Plus, type checking is a really nasty code smell.

Comment: I would like to have your problems :-)

Comment: > What is a workaround for that in production code? Also a bit nasty, but catch the exception and return `false`.

Comment: @Jay thank you, yes, that is a possibility, but it's too broad, unfortunately - I only want to handle the `SortedList` case

Comment: `catch (ArgumentNullException) { return false; }`? I know, it's ugly too.

Comment: i would actually say that the contains implementation is wrong because it should be looking at the values not the keys. Having said that - it is what it is, its not going to change so code round it

Comment: @pm100 it **is** looking at the values of the `Keys` collection, I don't see why the implementation is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

The `SortedList` class implements `IDictionary`, which specifies the `Key, value` nature of `SortedList`. Because of the way `IDictionary` implementations are expected to work (utilizing hashcodes in order to sort or index the keys), you cannot input a `null` object as a key, because `null` does not have a valid hashcode. For this reason, the `Contains(...)` method will throw an `ArguementInvalidException` when attempting to pass `null` into the parameter, as it is aware that `null` is not a valid key.

If you want to "fix" this for a production environment (which I wouldn't recommend, as this shouldn't really be an issue), I would recommend extending the `SortedList` class and overriding the `Contains(...)` method to return safely when passed the `null` arguement.

Comment: That's all true, but that is also far away from the original question. Yes, the `SortedList` is a dictionary, okay, but we're talking about `SortedList.Keys` here, which is not a dictionary - it's just a collection.

Comment: Plus, I only have access to the `HasItem` method, the `Main` method is consumer-defined code

Comment: Oh, but it appears that it's still in the same boat. The [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56(v=vs.110).aspx) states that different `Contains` methods will utilize whatever implementation best suites the nature of the parent object (it explicitly mentions `IDictionary` as well.) However, it does appear that the `Keys` property would likely implemented `ICollection` in such a way that it should act like a `List`, but it may behave more like it's parent object, the `IDictionary`. Of course, it could also just be a .NET quirk in the end.

Answer (score -2):

I found this line on MSDN: Type: T
The object to locate in the Collection. The value can be null for reference types.

EDIT: you need this using statement for System.Linq

using System.Linq;

```
       SortedList<string, int> temp = new SortedList<string, int>();
        bool test = HasItem(temp.Keys, null);


    public bool HasItem(ICollection<string> collection, object item)
    {
        return collection.Contains(item);
    }//This returns false when fed a null
```

I think by using Object as my parameter instead of string which is immutable My parameter is truly recognized as a reference type. Either way this function has been tested and works. Good luck.

Comment: How have you made it compile? The `ICollection<T>` does not have a `Contains(object value)` method declaration

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I'm running my code in asp.net MVC in visual studio 2015.  My framework is 4.5.  are you running on the same target framework that should be the only thing that matters in this instance. It compiles with no errors.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx), there's no such a method in this interface. Are you **100% sure** that there's no any extension methods that are provided for you in _your_ environment?

Comment: OK I went off and isolated the code and it seems you need a using statement you cannot get by with just  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; you must also include System.Linq. But as far as extensions go I write a lot of them but not for one for this yet.

Comment: Though this does indeed solve the exception being thrown in *this very example*, the code goes a completely different path. What if a user has a custom implementation of an `ICollection<T>` that he passes to the `HasItem` method? The approach you proposed would not go through this custom logic.